# RInside and Qt examples compilation error

Tags: c++, linux, g++, rinside

I'm new about RInside and I want to run the examples about QT

I get this error all the time I use "qmake" and "make" as say the README, and I really want to know what can I do about it.

```
$ g++ -Wl,-O1 -o qtdensity qtdensity.o main.o moc_qtdensity.o    -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lrt -ldl -lm -lblas -llapack -L/home/user/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/RInside/lib -lRInside -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/RInside/lib -lQtSvg -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llzma
collect2: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
make: *** [qtdensity] Error 1
```

I thought it was because I had not the library lzma, but I intalled it and I still get the same error.
What can I do?
 Can you help me please?

Comment: Add the library to the global path or put it in the known path of the linker.

Comment: Thanks for answer, do you know how can I do that??

Comment: Add these lines to your pro file `-L/*PATH_TO_YOUR_LIB*/ -llzma`

Comment: Install the corresponding header package: `sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev`. Ditto for whatever linking error you may have next.  You obviously need a full R development environment, and `sudo apt-get install r-base-dev` tries to help you get most dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for answer my questions. It works now! I feel so good for receive help of you, I want to give you some points or reputations for help me,but, I am really new at StackOverflow. Please be patient.

Comment: Dirk Eddelbuettel, Thanks  for your job!!!